# display google map with markers retrieved from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps

i am using PHP and MYSQL in order to retrieve data from the database. i need to embed Google Map and plot markers based on the retrieved data from the MYSQL database.

i am able to retrieve data from the database and display it on the web page as an XML format. **but without displaying the Google Map**

where is the error in the code?

i will appreciate any help.

## code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP
        */

        get_header();
          ?>
<html>

   <head>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js'></script>
    <style>

        BODY {font-family : Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size : 13px ; }

        #map_canvas { width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******************&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //This javascript will load when the page loads.
    jQuery(document).ready( function($){

            //Initialize the Google Maps
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var markersArray = [];
            var infos = [];

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
            //Load the Map into the map_canvas div
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            //Initialize a variable that the auto-size the map to whatever you are plotting
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            //Initialize the encoded string       
            var encodedString;
            //Initialize the array that will hold the contents of the split string
            var stringArray = [];
            //Get the value of the encoded string from the hidden input
            encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;
            //Split the encoded string into an array the separates each location
            stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

            var x;
            for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
            {
                var addressDetails = [];
                var marker;
                //Separate each field
                addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
                //Load the lat, long data
                var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[2], addressDetails[3]);
                //Create a new marker and info window
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: lat,
                    //Content is what will show up in the info window
                    content: addressDetails[0]
                });
                //Pushing the markers into an array so that it's easier to manage them
                markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
                    closeInfos();
                    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
                    //On click the map will load the info window
                    info.open(map,this);
                    infos[0]=info;
                });
               //Extends the boundaries of the map to include this new location
               bounds.extend(lat);
            }
            //Takes all the lat, longs in the bounds variable and autosizes the map
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            //Manages the info windows
            function closeInfos(){
           if(infos.length > 0){
              infos[0].set("marker",null);
              infos[0].close();
              infos.length = 0;
           }
            }

    });
    </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id='input'>


<?php
global $wpdb;
//Initialize your first couple variables
$encodedString = ""; //This is the string that will hold all your location data
$x = 0; //This is a trigger to keep the string tidy

//Now we do a simple query to the database
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from site_coordinates", ARRAY_N);


//Multiple rows are returned

foreach ($sql as $row) 
{
    //This is to keep an empty first or last line from forming, when the string is split
  //  if ( $x == 0 )
   // {
       //  $separator = "";
    //}
    //else
    //{
         //Each row in the database is separated in the string by four *'s
         $separator = "****";
    //}
    //Saving to the String, each variable is separated by three &'s
    $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
    "<p class='content'><b>Site ID :</b> ".$row[0].
    "<br><b>Lat:</b> ".$row[1].
    "<br><b>Long: </b>".$row[2].
    "<br><b>Height: </b>".$row[3].
    "<br><b>TX-Power: </b>".$row[4].
    "<br><b>TX-Center: </b>".$row[5].
    "<br><b>RX-Center: </b>".$row[6].
    "<br><b>Coverage Area: </b>".$row[7].  
    "</p>";
    $x = $x + 1;
}

?>
      <input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="<?php echo $encodedString; ?>" />  
   </div>
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </body>   
<?php
get_footer();
?>
</html>
```

using echo json_encode($row);
inside the foraeach loop

this was the result :

[image: result displayed]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating an HTML string from your DB in the PHP. Try creating the data that the googlemap JS is expecting to see, you could do this as a JSON object, easy enough to do in the PHP. Stop trying to display the DB data in HTML, instead think in JSON.

inside your foreach, try this for a start:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

this should start to give you an idea.

then look here:

```
 //Create a new marker and info window
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: lat,
                //Content is what will show up in the info window
                content: addressDetails[0]
            });
```

Comment: i used the json_encode ($row)  so your asking to replace **content:addressDetails[0] with json_encode** ??

Comment: i suggested using json_encode($row) so you can visualise the data and figure out how it needs to be presented to the googlemaps JS. I suggest you read through the googlemaps API documentation, as you are missing quite allot, eg: "position: lat" is not correct, it requires lat and long

Comment: i added the variable long to the position  but still having the same problem.
and i did json_encode($row) i will edit the question and add image for the result